# Can I restore documents from Recycle Bin that were already deleted from there?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, recycle-bin

A colleague accidentally deleted thousands of files from a document library.

Everything would be fine, but another colleague accidentally clicked on `Empty bin` instead of `Restore`.

Is it possible to recover it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If documents are deleted from first-stage recycle bin, those documents can be restored from **second-stage recycle bin**.

There is second-stage recycle bin in SharePoint which is accessible to site collection administrators.

A SharePoint site collection administrator can view and restore deleted items from the site collection Recycle Bin to their original locations.

If documents are deleted from the site collection Recycle Bin (second-stage recycle bin), it is **permanently deleted**.

**Documentations**:

1. [Restore deleted items from the site collection recycle bin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-deleted-items-from-the-site-collection-recycle-bin-5fa924ee-16d7-487b-9a0a-021b9062d14b)
2. [Restore items in the recycle bin that were deleted from SharePoint or Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-items-in-the-recycle-bin-that-were-deleted-from-sharepoint-or-teams-6df466b6-55f2-4898-8d6e-c0dff851a0be)